# getShaderPrecisionFormat return values

Tags: webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm confused about the method getShaderPrecisionFormat, what it's used for, and what it's telling me because for me it always returns the exact same precision for all arguments, only differences are between INT / FLOAT.

to be clear:

calls with gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER and gl.VERTEX_SHADER in combinations with gl.LOW_FLOAT, gl.MEDIUM_FLOAT and gl.HIGH_FLOAT always return

```
WebGLShaderPrecisionFormat { precision: 23, rangeMax: 127, rangeMin: 127 }
```

calls with gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER and gl.VERTEX_SHADER in combinations with gl.LOW_INT, gl.MEDIUM_INT and gl.HIGH_INT always return

```
WebGLShaderPrecisionFormat  { precision: 0, rangeMax: 24, rangeMin: 24 }
```

I experimented with also supplying two additional arguments "range" and "precision" but was unable to get any different results. I assume I made a mistake but from the [docs](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderPrecisionFormat.xml) I'm unable to figure out on my own how to use it correctly.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior as you. I assume this is happening because our browsers use the same amount of precision for low, medium and high. If I go to the following page which tests `getShaderPrecisionFormat` I see that all the tests pass. So I don't think anything is amiss. https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/misc/shader-precision-format.html

Comment: @Anton Yeah I've been on that page, too and also came to the same conclusions but I want to make sure I'm not missing something, because it's suspicious and could easily also be a mistake on my part. :)

Comment: What kind of hardware are you running this on? Using half-floats (16-bit floats) is fairly common on mobile devices. I don't think desktop GPUs typically bother with less than 32-bit precision. If you checked on desktops/laptops so far, run it on a typical tablet or phone, and you are likely to see something different.

Comment: @RetoKoradi You're right, I've only tested it on my laptop. Thanks, the thought that there would be a *lower* limit to the precision would *never* have occurred to me, but after googling around with that in mind it seems to be not that uncommon. I'd gladly accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using these calls correctly.

If you're running on a desktop/laptop, the result is not surprising. I would expect WebGL to be layered on top of a full OpenGL implementation on such systems. Even if these systems support ES 2.0, which mostly matches the WebGL feature level, that's most likely just a reduced API that ends up using the same underlying driver/GPU features as the full OpenGL implementation.

Full OpenGL does not really support precisions. It does have the keywords in GLSL, but that's just for source code compatibility with OpenGL ES. In the words of the GLSL 4.50 spec:

> Precision qualifiers are added for code portability with OpenGL ES, not for functionality. They have the same syntax as in OpenGL ES, as described below, but they have no semantic meaning, which includes no effect on the precision used to store or operate on variables.

It then goes on to define the use of IEEE 32-bit floats, which have the 23 bits of precision you are seeing from your calls.

You would most likely get a different result if you try the same thing on a mobile device, like a phone or tablet. Many mobile GPUs support 16-bit floats (aka "half floats"), and take advantage of them. Some of them can operate on half floats faster than they can on floats, and the reduced memory usage and bandwidth is beneficial even if the operations themselves are not faster. Reducing memory/bandwidth usage is critical on mobile devices to improve performance, as well as power efficiency.